Jupyter Lab: Ctrl-z/undo command not working, option is greyed out
Pretty much the title. The option to undo (or redo) the code changes are gone. If I type Ctrl-z nothing happens. My jupyter version:
jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.23.0
ipykernel        : 6.29.4
ipywidgets       : 8.1.2
jupyter_client   : 8.6.1
jupyter_core     : 5.7.2
jupyter_server   : 2.14.0
jupyterlab       : 4.1.6
nbclient         : 0.10.0
nbconvert        : 7.16.3
nbformat         : 5.10.4
notebook         : 7.1.2
qtconsole        : 5.5.1
traitlets        : 5.14.2



Anything in the web console logs? In general I would encourage reporting issues on JupyterLab issue tracker on github.
